# How to properly define a global function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on an interactive periodic table and trying to set up a button to dynamically change the colours of the buttons the elements are displayed on. However, when I run the function which should change the variable which stores which colour set the buttons should use it doesn't work. I understand that this function needs to be a global function but have been unable to find any suitable documentation on the topic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
colour="basic"
#Functions to create GUI
def colourset(colour):
    if colour=="basic":
        advanced()
        colour="advanced"
    elif colour=="advanced":
        basic()
        colour="basic"
    return(colour)
```

Comment: you means setting color as a global variable?

Answer (score 1):

To access a global variable in a function in Python you need to use `global`.

In your case:

```
def colourset():
    global colour
    .....
```

Comment: Thank you, fixed my problem!